# Bootstrap Affix issue on small viewports

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and it's JavaScript component "affix". I've got it to work on large screen (works fine, no issues), but I've run into a problem where, when I view the site on a smaller screen size. When I scroll down the page, the affix element initially follows, but when I get to the end right before the footer, it resets back to the top and stops working. Not sure why.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="sidebar my-affix"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.my-affix').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 20,
        bottom: function() {
            return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console when that happens? Can you set up a fiddle or link us?

Comment: Checked. No errors show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide a style for `.affix-bottom` and set it to `position: absolute` otherwise offset will apply a `position: relative` to that element and make it "pop" to the top after you reach the bottom of the page and scroll up.

Ref:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9342#issuecomment-22819766